# how to get values from dynamically created edittexts

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have created a tablelayout with dynamically created rows with 3 edittexts on every row. Say there are 5 rows with 3 edittexts on each, how can i get the the entered values from every first edittext from each row into an arraylits and calculating them.

Here is my code so far:

```
Public void addRow (View v) {
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
EditText et1 = new EditText(this);
EditText et2 = new EditText(this);
EditText et3 = new EditText(this);

idCount++;
mRowCount++;

et1.setTag(a + idCount);
et1.setText(a + idCount);
et2.setTag(b + idCount);
et2.setText(b + idCount);
et3.setTag(c + idCount);
et3.setText(c + idCount);

mLayout.addView(row);
row.setId(mRowCount);
row.addView(et1);
row.addView(et2);
row.addView(et3);
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(); //Generic ArrayList to Store your Strings

stringList.add(et1.getText()) ;//do this for your 3 textviews  
stringList.add(et2.getText()) ;
stringList.add(et3.getText()) ;
int count=0;
Iterator<String> iterator = stringList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        count=count+Integer.parseInt(iterator.next());
    }
```

Comment: I'm gonna insert int values, should i use arraylist<integer> or arraylist<edittext> and then try geting values from edittext arraylist ?

Comment: I updated my answer. you can do arraylist<String> and then convert the values inserted to ints:  
    Integer.parseInt(iterator.next())  
or you can parse it befor and use an ArrayList<Integer>. Use tha code that I provided and it is going to work. for what you need.  
cheers

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have the reference, you can access it with `getText()`.

2) If you haven't the reference, you have to set an ID to every `EditText` and the you could reach them with `findViewById()`

Answer (score 0):

by the getText() method

```
    edt1.gettext();
```

If you are entering string data then use toString() method as

```
   String res=edt1.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending how many rows you are likely to end up creating I would store a reference to the EditText objects when you create them. This may mean defining a row object for holding the three EditText objects, but just as east to create a Map:
    `Map<String, List<EditText>> mRows = new HashMap<String, List<<EditText>>();`

When creating the new row you can modify your code so as to store the references:

```
Public void addRow (View v) {
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
EditText et1 = new EditText(this);
EditText et2 = new EditText(this);
EditText et3 = new EditText(this);
List<EditText> row = new ArrayList<EditText>();
row.add(et1);
row.add(et2);
row.add(et3);
mRows.add("" + idCount, row);
```

I would also move that code into a separate function.

On submission you can now iterate over the map and pull the first entry out from each entry.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to take EditText(View) from your table layout and

```
TableRow tr = (TableRow) v.getParent();
```

// Index of column of table layout it should be an Integer value.

```
EditText et = (EditText) tr.getChildAt(Your_Index); 
EditText et1 = (EditText) tr.getChildAt(Your_Index);  
EditText et2 = (EditText) tr.getChildAt(Your_Index);
```

Then you will get value of that edittext with following code

```
String a = et.getText().toString(); 
String b = et1.getText().toString();
String c = et2.getText().toString();
```

Hope it will help you.